# How to access a field's parent fieldGroup from the OnChange event

Tags: angular-formly

OnChange of fields we have various validation that fires and, once that validation is completed we need to fire the parent fieldGroup's expressions.

My fields are grouped in pairs, so each fieldGroup holds two fields.
OnChange of one of the two fields I want to be able to access said field's parent fieldGroup in order to run its runExpression() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $scope.$parent.model inside the onChange function